# Why is Postgres transaction block so much slower? And how to solve?

Tags: postgresql, performance

Hoping someone with deeper postgres/database knowledge can share some insight.

Background:

I have a postgres v11 database running with some data. Now there is about 200k operations that I want to run on it as a single transaction (they should either all succeed or no changes made). The transactions include a mix of INSERT and UPDATE statements that also involve some triggers in the database.

If I run the query in a transaction then it takes about 70 minutes

```
BEGIN;
// statement
// statement
// statement
// ...
COMMIT;
```

If I remove the surrounding transaction block and simply run the queries then it will take 7 minutes.

```
// statement
// statement
// statement
// ...
```

Now I suspect the performance difference is related to transaction keeping some temporary tables which run into buffer size or indexing issues resulting in the slowdown, but since I don't have deep understanding of Postgres internals I don't actually know. I have tried changing various WAL settings, but without any significant difference.

So I have 2 questions:

1. Why is the transaction so much slower?
2. How can I run the batch of operations with the possibility of rollback without sacrificing performance to this degree?

---

**EDIT 1**

---

Extra information about tables and queries

I will try to give as much information as I can without revealing specifics (which I am not allowed).

There are 5 main tables related to this transaction - `accounts`, `currencies`, `transactions`, `transaction_logs`, `balance`.

`transactions` table has 3 foreign keys - 2 to `accounts` and 1 to `currencies`.

`balances` table has 2 foreign keys - 1 to `accounts` and 1 to `currencies`.

`transaction_logs` table has 3 foreign keys - 1 to `transactions`, 1 to `accounts`, 1 to `currencies`.

The transaction batch starts by inserting all relevant accounts and currencies. (about 10k accounts and 2 currencies)

Next it is a mix of inserts and updates of the transactions table - inserts are in groups up to 300 rows in a single insert, while updates are based on PK so only 1 row at a time. In total there are about 140k inserts and 60k updates.

Both inserts and updates in turn execute triggers which update the balances table and insert 2 rows into transaction_log table.

A typical insert looks like

`INSERT INTO transactions (from_account_id, to_account_id, currency_id, amount, metadata, status) VALUES (1, 1, 1, 10.00, '{"json":"blob"}', 'pending');`

A typical update looks like

`UPDATE transactions SET status = 'finished' WHERE id = 1;`

The programming environment is `node.js` and driver is `pg`.

---

**EDIT 2**

---

Apologies to everyone for the delay in providing more information - I was trying to create a closed test environment reproducing the error. And while doing this I managed to get closer to the crux of the problem. The structure itself seems irrelevant. **The slowdown is caused by updating the same row over and over again within the same transaction.**

The simplest reproduction I managed was creating a table with 2 fields, adding a few rows and then repeatedly updating the first row. Without a transaction the operation time stays relatively constant. Within a transaction however it starts climbing - at around 100k updates it is around 3 times higher than in the beginning. On my machine the total runtime difference for 100k updates test was 2.5x between a transaction and non-transaction version.

If however your data is more varied - not updating the same row, but different rows, then the problem does not occur and with a nicely distributed data the transaction is actually faster.

PS. Tested this with v12 as well and performs roughly the same.

*Does anyone have any ideas why this is happening?*

---

**EDIT 3**

---

I have created a repository to demonstrate this issue https://github.com/DeadAlready/pg-test

Comment: This is really strange. If at all, I would have expected the one without an explicit transaction to be slower. But without more details on how your tables look like and what exactly those 200.000 statements are doing, this is hard to tell. Which tool to do you use to run those statements? Or which programming language?

Comment: Could be a lack of vacuum; the row versions piling up. Are the insert/updates applied to the same set of tables/rows? What do the triggers do (history?)

Comment: Yes, without knowing the statements it is hard to say anything. If you profile both workloads with `perf top`, are there any functions that stand out?

Comment: How much is read from or done on those tables by other users. Because of MVCC for those users, preimages must be kept. Long running transactions can therefore lead to a bug overhead.

Comment: In the test setup I created there are no other users using the database at the time of the transaction - only this one batch of operations.

Comment: Are the foreign keys NOT DEFERRABLE, DEFERRABLE and deferred, or DEFERRABLE and not deferred?  Are the triggers BEFORE or AFTER?

Comment: The triggers are BEFORE triggers and all foreign keys are default (NOT DEFERRABLE) with the exception of transaction_id on the transaction_logs table which is DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED.

Comment: "*which is DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED*" - that could be a reason

Answer (score 9):

I took the question to postgres official mailinglist and this is the answer I got, which I will share here for future searchers.

---

TL;DR;

- **updating a single row multiple times inside a transaction is slow**
- **this is expected**
- **avoid doing that**

---

Link to the thread:

https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/7624.1581628574%40sss.pgh.pa.us

Full answer:

> Yeah, that's unsurprising.  Each new update creates a new version of
>   its row.  When you do them in separate transactions, then as soon as
>   transaction N+1 commits the system can recognize that the row version
>   created by transaction N is dead (no longer visible to anybody) and
>   recycle it, allowing the number of row versions present on-disk to
>   stay more or less constant.  However, there's not equivalently good
>   housekeeping for row versions created by a transaction that's still
>   running.  So when you do N updates in one transaction, there are going
>   to be N doomed-but-not-yet-recyclable row versions on disk.
>
> Aside from the disk-space bloat, this is bad because the later updates
>   have to scan through all the row versions created by earlier updates,
>   looking for the version they're supposed to update.  So you have an O(N^2)
>   cost associated with that, which no doubt is what you're observing.
>
> There isn't any really good fix for this, other than "don't do that".
>   David's nearby suggestion of using a temp table won't help, because
>   this behavior is the same whether the table is temp or regular.
>
> In principle perhaps we could improve the granularity of dead-row
>   detection, so that if a row version is both created and deleted by
>   the current transaction, and we have no live snapshots that could
>   see it, we could go ahead and mark the row dead.  But it's not clear
>   that that'd be worth the extra cost to do.  Certainly no existing PG
>   release tries to do it.
>
> regards, tom lane

Answer (score 1):

1. Why is the transaction so much slower?

   - Small Transactions are expensive because of the overhead of the log-writing. Which duplicates the cost of external operations.
   - Large Transactions are expensive because of the increasing management-overhead.

In my experience there is a optimal medium transaction-size.

2. How can I run the batch of operations with the possibility of rollback without sacrificing performance to this degree?

There are many new records in this transaction. Does this transaction only change those new records? How big is the influence of the algorithm on records already existing before. My idea behind that is, that you could build up the data in multiple mid-range -transactions very fast und just delete this new data if necessary in a separate transaction by removing those new records.

If there are changed existing records, you could move the manipulation of these existing records in one smaller transaction at the end of the algorithm. If a rollback becomes necessary, you can roll back this small transaction and afterwards remove those new records which hopefully can be identified quite easily.

Comment: This answer is insufficient - a generic reference to management-overhead doesn't explain why a transaction which is usually faster is in some cases not. And manually constructing a custom transaction mechanism really isn't a valid solution - it is very error prone and complicated.

Comment: I fear you will end up buying a commercial Dbms, much consulting and/or better Hardware.